# Resolving syntax error in line 7

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code, where I get the syntax error:

```
def cube(number):
return number*number*number
def by_three(number):
if number % 3==0:
    cube(number)
    return number
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that **indentation** in Python is extremely important since it defines where blocks start and end. I guess your code should be:

```
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3==0:
         cube(number)
         return number
    else:
         return False
```

Comment: Ok it worked. Thanks. However, i want to know the syntax for finding the cube of a number[not cube root]. Thanks

Comment: Use this operator `**`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

First, indent your code correctly.

```
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3==0:
         cube(number)
         return number
    else:
         return False
```

For `cube(number)`, you can use `base**exponent`

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3
```

Alternatively, `number^3` is the same as `number*number*number`, so

```
def cube(number):
    return number*number*number
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to indentation, you might want to use mathematical order of precedence and indicating a `*` for the multiplication.

This works for me with python 3

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

def cube(number):
  return (number * number * number)

def by_three(number):
  if (number % 3) == 0:
    cubed = cube(number)
    return cubed
  else:
    return False

def main():
   x = 3
   output = '%d' % by_three(x)
   print(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```